# How to make menu and logo color change in scrolling menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have fixed menu, and when scroll down, header menu change color in white. I have inserted this JQ:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300)
{   
   jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});
} else {
   jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"transparent"});
}
});
```

into [my site](http://deilbeatz.com/), that i work on it. But white color override all text and show only text when is close to it. So how to make logo in invert color, and text to be black in white background? I have found this CSS:

```
 -webkit-filter: invert(.8);
  filter: invert(.8);
```

But dont know how to include in JQ.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the text color of your #navigation element. You could do this like this:

```
jQuery('#navigation').css({"color":"black"});
```

EDIT:

From what i can see on your website, i came up with this:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300) {   
    jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});
    jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"black"});
  } else {
    jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"transparent"});
    jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"white"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but i allready have 

`jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});`

inside.. How to insert both?

Comment: Man, try replacing the code that you have in your site, with my. `jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"black"});` this changes the color of your text...

Comment: Ah, you added edited code. That is OK. I tested and works. One thing more.. How to make logo to be inverted in white background when scroll?

Comment: I tryed adding this code in JQ:

`jQuery('.site_logo').css({"-webkit-filter":"invert(.8)"});
       jQuery('.site_logo').css({"filter":"invert(.8)"});`

and make some change, but red color in logo make green. How to resolve this issue?