# How to make text and icons black in sticky header?

Tags: css, colors, header

I have issue with setting menu text and icons in sticky header to be black, in my [site](http://touchdowner.cz/). I searched for right class, but cant find it into CSS styles. I tryed this CSS:

```
.header-wrapper .stuck {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

but not make any changes. So how to make text and icons in sticky header black ?

Comment: Does your site even have a `.header-wrapper`?

Comment: Inserting :

`.header-wrapper {
  color:#000!important;
}`

Comment: dont make any change.

Comment: See image

http://i.imgur.com/RgaYRaV.png?1

Comment: I can't find any class with `.header-wrapper` that you are styling in your HTML code.

Comment: Ok so you have any idea how to make text and icons in sticky menu black?

Comment: try to load site now. Developer Mode was activated before.

Comment: So you need your icons & text to be black and background to be white?

Comment: Yes exactly. background is allready white, only text and icons what is in black header at top, in sticky need to be black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the website you've given, you just need to do remove the class named `.nav-dark` from the div having id `#masthead` when scrolled (or `.stuck` class is added with `.header-wrapper`).

Include jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use jQuery:

```
function customizeHeader() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ($('.header-wrapper').hasClass('stuck')) {
    $('#masthead').removeClass('nav-dark');
  } else {
    $('#masthead').addClass('nav-dark');
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(customizeHeader);
  customizeHeader();
});
```

You'll get something like:

[image]

Hope this is what you're trying to achieve and it helps!

Comment: @Dora Try this and let me know if this helps?

Comment: I cant edit CSS. I dont have access to styles files. Site is Wordpress. Any other sollution?

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Something like this

`    jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300)
    {   
    jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});
    } else {
    jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"transparent"});
    }
    });`

Comment: @Dora Wait. I'll post it soon.

Comment: OK, no problem. i can wait.

Comment: I inserted your JQ into my site, but dont see any change in sticky menu..

Comment: Maybe you can see this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152394/how-to-make-menu-and-logo-color-change-in-scrolling-menu

So something similar must be done here.

Comment: @Dora Your site *does not support jQuery*, see your console for the error. Include jquery - `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Ok, can be fixed via CSS then?

Comment: @Dora Can't you include jQuery on your site. Its simple, have a look at my updated answer it tells you how to include jQuery on your site.

Comment: I  Included jQuery into header, and inserted your JQ, but i dont see any change.. What s problem?

Comment: Check image: http://i.imgur.com/wyIukfo.png?1

that show that is included, but for some reason, not working.

Comment: Include jQuery before the code I've given. i.e. include jQuery in the `<head>` tag and then my given code after the `<footer>` ends at the bottom of the page. Currently you are trying to run my js code before including jquery. Browser always read the page from top to bottom - keep in mind.

Comment: That makes sense. How to change color on text? its grey atm, i want to be black ?